# Difference between Consecutive and cumulative

Tags: meaning

I'm a bit confused with the meaning of those words,
this is what i got when i googled it:

> Cumulative (adjective) : increasing by successive additions

> Consecutive (adjective):
> following one after the other in order : SUCCESSIVE

However, It's still confusing for me, especially the meaning of 'successive additions'

Can anybody tell me the difference using simple and understandable examples? thanks

Answer (score 5):

Consecutive: one after the other.  For example, Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday are *consecutive* days of the week.  Monday, Thursday, and Sunday are not consecutive.

Cumulative: adding up.  For example, if I have a bucket that can hold ten liters of water, but I add three liters of water, then four more liters, then five more liters, the *cumulative* amount of water is too much for the bucket to hold.  Any one amount could have been held by the bucket, but when I keep adding them ("successive additions"), it is too much.

Answer (score 1):

Many bronze statues will have a bright spot from people rubbing the statue ([wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statue_rubbing)). That bright spot is the *cumulative* effect of of thousands of fingers rubbing that spot over the years (ie., the wear is "increasing by successive additions", each rub "adding" some wear). Each *consecutive* person to rub the statue (ie., each rubber "one after the other") rubbed off a miniscule amount of the surface of the statue (probably not even enough to be measured, really). However: the *cumulative*  effect of all of those fingers is a bright spot.

---

One "standard" drink has the same amount of alcohol, be it in 12 ounces of beer, 5 of wine, 1.5 of stronger spirits (note: this is a rough approximation; [source](https://www.niaaa.nih.gov/alcohols-effects-health/overview-alcohol-consumption/what-standard-drink)). A healthy adult can process about 1 drink per hour ([source](https://shop.ucsc.edu/alcohol-other-drugs/alcohol/your-body.html)). So: each *consecutive* drink will increase my blood alcohol content, and each *consecutive* hour will decrease my blood alcohol content by a roughly equal amount. Thus, my *cumulative* blood alcohol content is (again, to a rough approximation) equal to the number of drinks I've had minus the number of hours since the first drink (both of which reset when my blood alcohol content reaches zero). *This is not medical or legal advice, and there are a huge number of fine details that this glosses over for ease of being an example.*

---

There's an illustration of "eternity":

> in lower pomerania is the diamond mountain, which is two miles high, two miles wide, and two miles deep.  Every hundred years a little bird comes and sharpens its beak on it, and when the whole mountain is worn away by this, then the first second of eternity will be over.

Each *consecutive* beak-sharpening wears away slightly at the diamond mountain; the *cumulative* effect of those birds is to wear the mountain wholly away.

-- [source](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Espok/grimmtmp/117.txt) (one of many variations, I'm sure)